# JPA dont get Objects to ArrayList in ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, jpa, arraylist, many-to-many

There are my two class Group and User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "getGroupbyUserEmail", query = "SELECT g.group_id, g.name, g.description FROM  `GROUPS` AS g LEFT JOIN user_group AS c ON c.group_id = g.group_id LEFT JOIN USERS AS u ON u.user_id = c.user_id WHERE u.email =? ")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Group.getAllGroups", query = "SELECT e FROM Group e"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Group.getGroupByName", query = "SELECT e FROM Group e WHERE e.name=:name") })
public class Group implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Set<User> users;

    public Group() {

        users = new HashSet<User>(0);
    }

    public Group(String name, String description, Set<User> users) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Group(String name, String description) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "groups")
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
```

and User:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.getUserByEmail", query = "SELECT e FROM User e WHERE e.email = :email ")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email,
            String password, Set<Group> groups) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_group", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }
```

My problem is that when I get the User object from the database, retrieve all the fields correctly, the console I see two queries select, one to the User and the other related to the Group but unfortunately ArrayList should contain the group is empty.

I try to change fetchType Lazy-> Eager but without the expected result

Comment: Does it throw any exception? Try initializing your Sets like this: `private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);` or in the constructor.

Comment: Which ArrayList are you talking about? There is no ArrayList in the code you posted. Are you aware that, by using EAGER on the two sides of the association, using a user will load all his groups, which will loa all the users of the loaded groups, which will load all the groups of the loaded users, etc. etc. until all the referenced groups and users are loaded in memory. You probably don't want that.

Comment: arturo i Initialize Set in this way like you show me.
JB Nizet i understand this, i try in this way but that doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Now when i try do get user mefhod find() by id, a receive Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError>

In User class I set fetch = FetchType.EAGER but in group i set fetch = FetchType.LAZY

Comment: Are there any entries in the "user_group" join table?  How are you creating the entities and have you set both sides of the bidirectional relationship?  By that, I mean, when you add a group to users.groups list do you also add that same user to the group.users list?  This is required by JPA, otherwise the collection will only show the values when the entity is refreshed from the database.

Comment: I still don't see what ArrayList you're talking about.

Comment: The _StackOverflowError_ I think is caused by the eager fetching loading everything into memory, as JB Nizet said, so get rid of that; it's not going to solve the problem. Your problem must be somewhere else, but we need more info. Maybe post the SQL of your tables.

Comment: I update my post, paste whole class. 
Here is link to picrure with my database design http://hostmypicture.com/images/1jij.jpg